# Facebook OAUTH token is always NULL

Tags: php, facebook, oauth, facebook-oauth

Ever I send a token request to Facebook I receive a `NULL` response. Not a exception or success response. Always `NULL`

```
$this->facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'APP ID', 
    'secret' => 'APP SECRET',
    'cookie' => true
));

if(isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $token = $this->facebook->api('/oauth/access_token', 'GET', array(
        'client_id' => 'APP ID',
        'client_secret' => 'APP SECRET',
        'redirect_uri' => 'http://mywebsite.com?route=' . urlencode('account/connect/facebook/'),
        'code' => $_GET['code']
    ));

    print_r($token); // NULL
    exit;
} else {
    $this->redirect($this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                'redirect_uri' => 'http://mywebsite.com?route=' . urlencode('account/connect/facebook/')
            )
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$token = $this->facebook->api('/oauth/access_token',
```

You can not use Facebook::api to makes this call, because that method expects a JSON response, which this endpoint does *not* respond with.

But why would you want to do this anyway? The PHP SDK already has the functionality to detect a passed `code` parameter and exchange it for an access token included, and does it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just do:

```
$token = $this->facebook->getAccessToken();
```

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getAccessToken/

Comment: No, because I will get: `Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user`, because default access token is like this `APPID|APPSECRET`